# Wildfly image and http access to show image with websocket

Tags: java, websocket, wildfly

I generate dynamically some svg file from server side into the directory provided by `System.getProperty("jboss.server.temp.dir")`

While files are well generated I can not to provide a link to access remotely to the SVG. I sent the URI link through ServerEndPoint Decoder. But client side the link is unreachable.

What is the way to do it ?

It seem I can not to use the servlet technique as websocket use ServerEndPoint,

**solved**

I edited the server node from standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/foo_svg" handler="images"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="images" path="${jboss.server.temp.dir}/foo_server/foo_svg" directory-listing="true"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

This should to add an external resources directory and generated files go into `${jboss.server.temp.dir}/foo_server/foo_svg` . They are still reachable using : `http://localhost:8080/foo_svg/bar.svg`

Regards